# How to customize the number of items for a drop-down list on the Outlook Ribbon?

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbon

We have a dropdown list on ribbon for Outlook appointments.

- We have about 1500 items in the drop down list. However it cannot display them.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZOwn.png)
- We have tested with about 1000 items, it shows normally.

How to customize the number of items in the dropdown?

Note: I'm using: Outlook for Microsoft 365

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `getItemCount` callback which gets the number of items to be displayed. The callback has the following signature:

```
C#: int GetItemCount(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetItemCount(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)

C++: HRESULT GetItemCount([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] long *count)

Visual Basic: Function GetItemCount(control As IRibbonControl) As Integer
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: We used `getItemCount`. However, after get the item number will be displayed. It does nothing next.

Comment: What is your ribbon XML for the drop down control? How do you use other callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display 1,500 items, you really need to rethink your UI and either show the data grouped in a tree-like structure (sub-menus would work) or display a separate window with the list of all items that the user can search through.

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific?

Comment: Also, We had a separate window and it displayed 1500 items very well. However, we also want it to show up on the ribbon.

Comment: You can group the appointments by month / day / time - hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what you do. Still, a static ribbon with 1,500 items is too much for the ribbon. You really need to rethink your design.